# Dynamic Flowfile Transfer Scheduling Using Quartz in NiFi Processors

Tags: java, apache-nifi, quartz-scheduler, scheduling

I have been assigned a requirement in my project i.e. is to implement a Quartz scheduler with in a custom NiFi processor.

At the initial stage of work, the functionality I need to develop is that to schedule the transfer of the flowfile from its preceding processor to its defined processor at a scheduled time.

I will the receive the scheduling instructions as a dynamic parameter and need to schedule it accordingly using quartz library.

So at the base level of development I am hardcoding the scheduling expressions (CRON expression).

-> What I have tried

- I have created a custom processor and have added the quartz library.
- Then created a class (ScheduleFlowFile) to implement the org.quartz.Job and have implemented the abstract method execute which is used to execute the logic at the scheduled time. Within this class I am getting the reference to the ProcessSession, ProcessContext variables of the custom NiFi processor that I have created using JobDataMap while defining a JobDetail which is to be scheduled.

```
package com.chellyvishal.scheduleQuartz;

import org.apache.nifi.flowfile.FlowFile;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.ProcessContext;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.ProcessSession;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.Relationship;
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobDataMap;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class ScheduleFlowFile implements Job {
    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {

        JobDataMap dataMap = jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();

        ProcessSession session = (ProcessSession) dataMap.get("processSession");
        ProcessContext context = (ProcessContext) dataMap.get("processContext");
        Relationship success   = (Relationship)   dataMap.get("successRelationship");

        FlowFile getFlowFile   = session.get();

        session.transfer(getFlowFile, success);
    }
}
```

- Inside MyProcessors.class with in the onTrigger method I have created the JobDetail and the trigger to run them at the instructed schedule

```
public class MyProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    public static final Relationship SUCCESS = new Relationship.Builder()
            .name("success")
            .description("FlowFiles that have been successfully processed")
            .build();

    public static final Relationship FAILURE = new Relationship.Builder()
            .name("failure")
            .description("FlowFiles that have failed processing")
            .build();
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .

    .
    @Override
    public void onTrigger(final ProcessContext context, final ProcessSession session) {
        FlowFile flowFile = session.get();
        if ( flowFile == null ) {
            return;
        }
        // TODO implement

        try {
            scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        long currentTime         = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String uniqueJobIdentifier = "sampleJob_" + currentTime;
        String cronExpression = "0/10 0/2 * ? * * *";

        JobDetail jobDetail = newJob(ScheduleFlowFile.class)
                .withIdentity(uniqueJobIdentifier, "newGroupFirst")
                .build();

        jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("processSession", session);
        jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("processContext", context);
        jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("successRelationship", SUCCESS);

        //A simple trigger which runs once after 5 seconds from the moment of getting initiated
        Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("newTrigger"+currentTime, "newGroupFirst")
                .startNow()
                .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                        .withIntervalInSeconds(5)
                        .withRepeatCount(0))
                .build();
        //A CRON trigger which schedules the job according the CRON expression
        Trigger cronTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("newCRONTrigger"+currentTime", "newGroupFirst")
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronExpression))
                .build();

        try {
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


}
```

[image: But this is the error I am facing]

And I am stuck here and not getting an idea how to deal with it

Comment: 1st - idea sounds wrong. when you are saying "Dynamic Flowfile Transfer Scheduling" where you are going to take the dynamic schedule expression? 2nd - please provide full stacktrace of the exception from a log file.

Comment: 1. hey @daggett I am going to extract the CRON expression from the attributes of the incoming flowfile and provide it to the trigger that I'm going to create the with in the onTrigger method.

Comment: 2. Here is the exception from the log file
`'ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.a.n.c.r.StandardProcessSession Failed to asynchronously commit session StandardProcessSession[id=2443] for MyProcessor[id=09869d8f-018e-1000-97e5-f452b244e917]
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception`

Comment: the continued part of the exception

`.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=5330c5d2-daa1-408f-a192-24234b6caa10,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1709556822282-1, container=default, section=1], offset=2, length=1],offset=0,name=5330c5d2-daa1-408f-a192-24234b6caa10,size=1] transfer relationship not specified. This FlowFile was not created in this session and was not transferred to any Relationship via ProcessSession.transfer()'`

Comment: @daggett please let me know if my explanation is not to the point I will try explaining it in a better and more understandable way.

Comment: 2. Please put stacktrace into question as a text. The error is self explainable: `This FlowFile was not created in this session and was not transferred to any Relationship via ProcessSession.transfer()` Somehow you have created flowfile out of session and did not transfer it anywhere. Any file you are creating must be transferred to some relationship or dropped. Otherwise the session could not be committed.

Comment: 1. what if you have 10 flowfiles in queue with 10 absolutely different crone expressions - what should happend?

Comment: 1. answering to 10 flowfiles having 10 different CRON expression then, they should be processed according to their respective logic handling at their respective CRON expression.

Comment: ah. here is misreading: cron defines repeating action when you have just one file... what's granularity/accuracy of this scheduling? asking because i'm thinking only about one option here: https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/bda9b6360d932bb07af387e38a243cb7f3bceb2b/nifi-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processor/ProcessSession.java#L330 - `get(FlowFileFilter filter)` allows you to get files from inbound queue by filter, and filter could check if file is ready to be processed.